# Google Analytics: Custom variables issue difference in data

Tags: seo, google-analytics

We’ve set up tracking through custom variables in Google Analytics to measure which offices are getting the most traffic. The custom var consists out of the key (=office) and value = (office name).

In our Custom Var tab in audience we get no data (actually we got 1 hit, but we think the data is way off).

When we setup advanced segments with the filters on key and value we get the correct data. Now we are wondering why we aren’t getting that data in the custom var tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my own problem:

Sequence of the snippet wasn't ok, you need to declare your custom vars BEFORE ['_trackPageview'] not AFTER it.

Hope this could be of use to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

For event tracking will only reflect the data when visitors perform specified task i.e clicked on button, click on download fine, click on play button etc...

Make sure your code is installed properly and load the same when visitors perform specific event.

For more information, kindly visit https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables